# How to hide one tabbarcontroller and show anothe on click of a button..?

Tags: iphone

I am showing a ExchangeWardrobe view.In this view i have a button Mywardrobe on click on this button,opens User’s own Exchange Wardrobe.This will have following 3 tabs..one is myProducts view..in which there is one button offer..click on this offer button open Product detail page..which is also in another tabbarcontroller..so I want to ask Is it possible that a class of one tabbarcontroller can call another class of another tabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate you can add and remove tab bar controllers from your main window (ie [window addSubview:usersWardrobeTabBarController.view]).

just create a method in your app delegate that swaps these views adds/removes them from your window. Or if memory isn't an issue then add them both and hide/unhide them.

Comment: but I do not want to use it from App Delegate..then how?